# Communication between computation server and web server

Tags: web-services, ssh, communication, rpc, denial-of-service

I have:

- a machine (C) which is responsible for some computation (not publicly available),
- a machine (W) which is a publicly available web server,
- a machine (G) which is also publicly available and in the same LAN as C.

I am looking for a way for W to serve as interface for C, that is, given a request made on a web page on W, W communicates with C through G, gets its response, and communicate it back to the client.

I am not very confident in RPC, webservices, and related technologies. I figured a double ssh tunnel with a bit of polling on C would do the trick.

What do you think would be the best security (DoS-wise) / simplicity (implementation) tradeoff ?